# unaryExpr from Eigen dosn't work with function from the same struct

Tags: c++, struct, eigen

I have code that applies sigmoid function to Eigen Matrix using unaryExpr

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Core>

#include <iostream>

using Eigen::MatrixXd, std::cout, std::cin;

double sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
}

struct Network {
public:
    MatrixXd sigmoid_matrix(MatrixXd z) {
        return z.unaryExpr(&sigmoid);
    }
};

int main() {
    Network net;
    Eigen::MatrixXd m(1, 4);
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    cout << net.sigmoid_matrix(m);
}
```

it works fine, however, if i put `double sigmoid(double x)` function in `Network` struct:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Core>

#include <iostream>

using Eigen::MatrixXd, std::cout, std::cin;

struct Network {
public:
    double sigmoid(double x) {
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
    }
    MatrixXd sigmoid_matrix(MatrixXd z) {
        return z.unaryExpr(&Network::sigmoid);
    }
};

int main() {
    Network net;
    Eigen::MatrixXd m(1, 4);
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    cout << net.sigmoid_matrix(m);
}
```

it fails to compile with this error:

```
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h:272:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<double (Network::*)(double), const double&>'
  272 |   typedef typename std::invoke_result<F, ArgTypes...>::type type1;
      |                                                             ^~~~~
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h:273:31: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<double (Network::*)(double), const double&>'
  273 |   typedef remove_all_t<type1> type;
      |                               ^~~~
```

What causes the problem here?

full error message here:

```
PS D:\Projects\c++\NeuralNetwrokNumbers> g++ -I D:/Projects/c++/eigen network.cpp -o network.exe
In file included from D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/Core:169,
                 from D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from network.cpp:1:
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h: In instantiation of 'struct Eigen::internal::result_of<double (Network::*(const double&))(double)>':
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseUnaryOp.h:26:28:   required from 'struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >'
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseUnaryOp.h:97:7:   required from 'class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOpImpl<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::Dense>'
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseUnaryOp.h:58:7:   required from 'class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >'     
network.cpp:19:27:   required from here
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h:272:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<double (Network::*)(double), const double&>'
  272 |   typedef typename std::invoke_result<F, ArgTypes...>::type type1;
      |                                                             ^~~~~
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h:273:31: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<double (Network::*)(double), const double&>'
  273 |   typedef remove_all_t<type1> type;
      |                               ^~~~
In file included from D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/Core:292:
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >':
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:51:34:   required from 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >'
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseUnaryOp.h:97:7:   required from 'class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOpImpl<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::Dense>'
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseUnaryOp.h:58:7:   required from 'class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >'     
network.cpp:19:27:   required from here
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:79:17: error: 'coeff' has not been declared in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   79 |     using Base::coeff;
      |                 ^~~~~
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:80:17: error: 'coeffByOuterInner' has not been declared in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   80 |     using Base::coeffByOuterInner;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:81:26: error: 'operator()' has not been declared in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   81 |     using Base::operator();
      |                          ^
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:82:26: error: 'operator[]' has not been declared in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   82 |     using Base::operator[];
      |                          ^
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:83:17: error: 'x' has not been declared in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   83 |     using Base::x;
      |                 ^
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:84:17: error: 'y' has not been declared in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   84 |     using Base::y;
      |                 ^
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:85:17: error: 'z' has not been declared in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   85 |     using Base::z;
      |                 ^
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:86:17: error: 'w' has not been declared in 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   86 |     using Base::w;
      |                 ^
In file included from D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/Core:293:
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, 
-1, -1> > >':
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseUnaryOp.h:97:7:   required from 'class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOpImpl<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::Dense>'
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseUnaryOp.h:58:7:   required from 'class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >'     
network.cpp:19:27:   required from here
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:78:17: error: 'coeff' has not been declared in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   78 |     using Base::coeff;
      |                 ^~~~~
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:81:17: error: 'eval' has not been declared in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   81 |     using Base::eval;
      |                 ^~~~
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:82:25: error: 'operator-' has not been declared in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   82 |     using Base::operator-;
      |                         ^
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:85:25: error: 'operator*=' has not been declared in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   85 |     using Base::operator*=;
      |                         ^~
D:/Projects/c++/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:86:25: error: 'operator/=' has not been declared in 'Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<double (Network::*)(double), const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::Base'
   86 |     using Base::operator/=;
      |                         ^~
```

Comment: Try `static double sigmoid(double x){...}`. Unless you actually need to access (non-static) members of `Network` -- in that case you need to pass some kind of lambda function or `std::bind` expression.

Comment: To call a member function, the code also needs an object that has such a member. In essence. something usable as the `this` pointer.

Comment: `static double sigmoid(double x){...}` worked! So, as i understood, compiler should be able to call `double sigmoid(double x){...}` function even if `Network` doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, [static member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_member_functions) are like regular functions but exist within the namespace of a class, have access to private members, etc